# How to set a default values to input field type in Prestashop backoffice in renderform

Tags: forms, prestashop-1.7

In renderform I have one input field and its type is "text". How to set a value to that input field, so at every time when the form is loaded the value should be displayed. I am using Prestashop 1.7.

Sample code:

```
array(
    'type'     => 'text',
    'label'    => $this->l('VENDOR_SERVER_IP'),
    'name'     => 'serverip',
    'size'     => 50,
    'class' => 'fixed-width-xxl',
    'required' => true,
    'desc'     => $this->l('Please enter your server ip.')
),
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `fields_value` property

```
$helper = new HelperForm();
//...
$helper->fields_value = array(
     'serverip' => 'x:x:x:x'
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have no option to pass default value of input field in the form array. To provide default value, you have to use `fields_value` property of form helper.

```
$hlper = new HelperForm();  
$value = 'Your already saved value if any';  
if (empty($value)) {  
  $value = 'your default value';  
}  

$hlper->field_values = array('YOUR_FORM_INPUT_NAME' => $value);  

echo $hlper->generate($your_form_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

There we have another way to do that, It is not what you want but it is one of the best alternative

```
                 [
                    'type' => 'html',
                    'label' => 'Information',
                    'disabled' => true,
                    'name' => 't',
                    'form_group_class' => 'tt',
                    'html_content' => $this->context->smarty->fetch(
                        'module:' . $this->name . 'tril.tpl'
                    ),
                ],
```

// Here you can write the custom input field of whatever you what to show here

Note please assign the variables for smarty will use in your tpl like,

```
$this->context->smary->assign([
'Var1' => $name,
'Vae2' => $Address
]);
```